# how to make incoming call in bluestacks

Tags: adb, putty, bluestacks, incoming-call

I want to connect to bluestacks with ADB and make incoming call

I know that this code make incoming call in android :

> gsm call +1234567

but I cant connect to bluestack
i used this code for connect to bluestacks

> adb connect localhost:5554

but ***CMD*** show this error for me :

> unable to connect to :5554

then i used [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) for connect to blue stack but i saw similar error

thanks of any response :)